# display *doc,*xls,*pdf in browser window instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, .doc

i want to display *doc,*xls,*pdf in browser window instead of their respected application. i have tried following code, but no luck it prompt me dialog for save/open instead of displaying in browser

```
    //Set the appropriate ContentType.
    Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
    //Get the physical path to the file.
    string FilePath = MapPath("wordfile.doc");
    //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + "wordfile.doc");
    Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
    Response.End();
```

please help
thanks

Comment: you cannot do it if browser doesn't support this function

Comment: It's a bit like asking "Why can't I open a doc in paint?"...

Answer (score 0):

for any of these proprietary formats you need browser plugins/extensions or ActiveX for IE
Am not sure if its available for office formats.
For PDF setting the `content type to "application/pdf"`  and `Content-Disposition to inline` should work.